# How to get display time in same format as in recorded zone format?

Tags: java, date

I have date format which is expected to store time zone information:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateWithZoneFormat
            = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Example date value,

```
2019-01-18T07:00:00.000+0530
```

The zone constant in the above date is Asia/Calcutta ( +0530 ), [Reference.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19563-01/819-4437/anovd/index.html)

Now while displaying on a machine which is in different time zone, I want above date to show the time in the same zone as recorded in above date i.e. +530, This is not constant zones can be changed based on users country.

My display code in java as below :

```
SimpleDateFormat dateWithZoneFormat
            = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
SimpleDateFormat displayDateFormat
            = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
Date date = DateUtils.getZoneDate("2019-01-18T07:00:00.000+0530");
                    String displayDate = DateUtils.displayDateFormat.format(date);
                    displayTag = displayDate + " " + displayTag;
```

Problem with the above code is, It picks the default zone of the machine on which it is running while creating display time.

In simple words, if the time recorded in +0530 zone while displaying it should show display time in +0530 zone if it is recorded in +0100 zone it should display in the same zone time.

How can I show above date in same zone format where it was recorded, Not the one where it is getting displayed ( i.e. not in machine default time zone ).

Is there any way I can extract just zone information in the above date String?

Comment: Step 1) Use `java.time`

Comment: `java.util.Date` objects do not contain timezone information. There is no such thing  as a date *"recorded in +0530 zone"*. As @Michael said, use `java.time`.

Comment: A `java.util.Date` object does not know anything about timezones. Specifically, it does not remember the timezone that was in the string that it was parsed from. You can set the timezone on the `SimpleDateFormat` object to make it print in a specific timezone (instead of the default) but what the zone was in the original string is not something you can get out of the `Date` object. As Michael says, this is much easier if you use the `java.time` classes such as `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` instead of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Did you search before asking? I’m pretty sure that similar questions have been asked answered more than once before. So you probably could have found a good answer faster that way.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, I did search, most suggestions about ZonedDateTime, We have some legacy code & data making use of SimpleDateFormatter date formats,  Unable to find how to migrate to new approach, But your answer & suggestion will be a good starting point to migrate to new date time APIs with solution for legacy data, Thanks

Comment: To convert back-and-forth between legacy and modern date-time objects, call new methods added to the old classes with `from…` and `to…` naming. `Instant` - `java.util.Date`. `ZonedDateTime` - `GregorianCalendar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### OffsetDateTime of java.time

```
    DateTimeFormatter recordedFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX");
    DateTimeFormatter displayFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-01-18T07:00:00.000+0530", recordedFormatter);
    String displayDateTime = dateTime.format(displayFormatter);
    System.out.println(displayDateTime);
```

This snippet outputs:

> 01/18/2019 07:00 AM

The time from the recorded string is preserved. The time is displayed at the same UTC offset.

Opposite the old-fashioned `Date`, an `OffsetDateTime` has a UTC offset so keeps the same time of day across parsing and formatting.

Usage: Asia/Calcutta is a *time zone*. `+05:30` is an *offset*, They are not the same. For example, Asia/Colombo is currently at the same offset, but is still considered a different time zone.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.